# Using AGOL feature services in QGIS using OAUTH2 authentication

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online, authentication, token

Just wondering if anyone has managed to add a secure AGOL feature service using the *OAUTH2* protocols.

I have tried adapting the workflow from [north road](https://north-road.com/2020/06/04/securely-accessing-enterprise-arcgis-portal-sites-through-qgis/)

I can get the Authentication to run but it doesn't apply the generated token to the feature layer request. The authentication token is cached in the connection details but doesn't work for the layer request.

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice here.. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/47142

Make sure your `Oauth2` settings include

```
Access method: Header

Token header: X-Esri-Authorization
```

This will correctly pass the token to the layer request.

Answer (score 0):

North Road (Disclosure I am the Product Manager there) have recently updated the services in QGIS and have provided instructions here:  [Securely accessing ArcGIS Online (AGOL) and enterprise ArcGIS Portal sites through QGIS (2022 update!)](https://north-road.com/2022/09/16/securely-accessing-arcgis-online-agol-and-enterprise-arcgis-portal-sites-through-qgis-2022-update/)